# background color not changing on hover css

Tags: html, css

I used this for styling navigation bar of my webpage but the color is not changing on hover

```
.nav {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
}

.nav li a:hover,.nav li a:active {
    background-color:#7A991A;
}

.nav li a:link,.nav li a:visited {
    display:block;
    width:9em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<ul class = "nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Our Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

can someone suggest what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you include the html? What immediately comes to mind is to wonder whether the 'a' element actually has height.

Comment: @Wisam http://jsfiddle.net/BcJR8/

Comment: @Semicolon : I have added the HTML code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either add `!important` here:

```
.nav li a:hover,.nav li a:active {
    background-color:#7A991A !important;
}
```

Or move the properties for `:hover` (and `:active`) after those for `:link`.

Comment: Its working. thanks a lot! but I don't understand whats the problem with writing it before `:link`?

Comment: @user3131961 CSS gets read linear from top to bottom, by declaring `a:hover` before `a`, my guess is any state declared before `a` is being overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.nav a:link` with `.nav li a`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aTjLD/1/)

```
  .nav li a, .nav li a:visited {
   /*here^^^*/
            display:block;
            width:9em;
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            background-color:#98bf21;
            text-align:center;
            padding:4px;
            text-decoration:none;
            text-transform:uppercase;
        }
```

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: @user3131961 : do you have any other `nav` class css too...??

Comment: I tried it, on my code. only working for the middle link bt on ur demo it works on all of them. I don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine now in the fiddle.

```
.nav {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
}

.nav li a:link,.nav li a:visited {
    display:block;
    width:9em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.nav li a:hover,.nav li a:active {
    background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
}
.nav li a:visited{
    background-color:#98bf21;
}
.nav li a:hover,.nav li a:active {
    background-color:#7A991A;
}

.nav li a{
    display:block;
    width:9em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `a:hover` is covered by `a:link` or so on.

I guess, Since `a:hover` is of the same level with `a:link`, Css class at the lower position of the file has higher priority.

You can refer to this:

[resolve css conflict](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/advanced_conflict.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JAJ9U/).

```
.nav {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
}

.nav-link {
    display:block;
    width:9em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.nav-link:hover,.nav-link:active {
    background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

1. it's not a good practice to nest too many tags, give it a class.
2. use `:link :visited :hover :active` only when you want to rewrite the default styles.
3. css is cascading style sheet, order matters, put .nav-link first to normalize default styles and then overwritten default with `:hover` and `:active`.
4. `!important` is not a good practice here, just rearrange the order.

Comment: I tried it. it was working but then I realised that when I click on the link, the color still remains the same.